# Plots getting replaced instead of showing a new plot

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create multiple plots in my Jupyter notebook. However, when I create one, it replaces the one before it instead of creating a brand new graph. Ex.

```
#plotting revenue_adj vs vote_average data
df.plot.scatter(x='revenue_adj',y='vote_average',s=.5,title='Average Movie Vote per Budget',figsize=(8,5));
```

creates a scatter plot, but when I try to plot below it (on a new code line),

```
df.groupby('genres')['vote_average'].mean().plot()
```

it replaces the above plot instead of creating a new one under that code. What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Remember, the plotting functions of pandas use actually matplotlib.

So you can use matplotlib figure() or subplots() functions to create new figures:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
df.plot.scatter()

fig = plt.figure()
df.plot.scatter()

# | or using subplots()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
df.plot.scatter(ax=ax[0])
df.plot.scatter(ax=ax[1])
```

Comment: @tarik-hodzic If this answer solved your problem, would you mind [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) it? I'd appreciate it.